# I'd like to keep unchanged value of a field but the datebase made it to ""

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, forms

```
<div class="col-xs-2">
    <label for="NomPrenom">Nom et Prénom </label>
    <input type="text" name="NomPrenom" placeholder="NomPrenom" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $NomPrenom ?>"/>
</div>
<?php }?>
```

But I don't like that the user change the value, I try to use

```
<input type="text" disabled="disabled" name="NomPrenom" placeholder="NomPrenom" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $NomPrenom ?>"/>
```

If I update the database the value of the field `NomPrenom` changes to "". How can I keep the value of the disabled field unchanged?

Comment: Disabled fields are not submitted by the browser. Use a hidden field. Or don't expose the value on the client side at all.

Answer (score 0):

Your input is not submitted by the browser on purpose because the field is disabled.

Of you need thar value, just use an additional field marked s **hidden**, and store the information you need there.

Hidden fields are submitted like regular ones, so you can read them without hassle in the backend.

Comment: thank you so much but i solved the probleme by puting readonly ="readonly" the field is showen to the client and stored to the database and can't be changed

Comment: thank you so much but i can't see any field disabled? where is it?

Comment: Have a look at [W3C](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp), this should help you